# How to catch curl error i.e time out in multicurl environment

Tags: libcurl

I know how to catch curl error(time out error) message in single curl request. It's something like as follows.

```
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 100);
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
```

If res is not curl_ok then it is some error like CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT 
 etc. But i want to know ,how to do that when we use multicurl request 
 where we use curl_multi_add_handle to add every curl request.How to set 
 timeout time and how to catch error message.

```
   bool cuev_emit(struct curlev *cuev, char *url, struct curl_slist *headers,
curlev_cb_t cb, void *cb_data)
 {
struct curlex *ex = NULL;
CURL *easy = curl_easy_init();
CURLMcode code;
if (!easy) {
    xsyslog(LOG_WARNING, "curl_easy_init() failed for url '%s' (errno: %d)",
            url, errno);
    return false;
}
curl_easy_setopt(easy, CURLOPT_URL, url);
curl_easy_setopt(easy, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0L);

curl_easy_setopt(easy, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);

curl_easy_setopt(easy, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, _curl_write_cb);
if (cb) {
    ex = calloc(1, sizeof(*ex));
    if (!ex) {
        xsyslog(LOG_WARNING, "cuev_emit() failed: calloc(%d) with errno: %d",
               (int)sizeof(*ex), errno);
        curl_easy_cleanup(easy);
        return false;
    }
    curl_easy_setopt(easy, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, ex);
    curl_easy_setopt(easy, CURLOPT_PRIVATE, ex);
} else {
    curl_easy_setopt(easy, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, NULL);
    curl_easy_setopt(easy, CURLOPT_PRIVATE, NULL);
}

if (headers) {
    /* TODO: добавить хидеры */
}

if ((code = curl_multi_add_handle(cuev->multi, easy)) != CURLM_OK) {
    xsyslog(LOG_WARNING, "curl_multi_add_handle() failed for url '%s', code: %d",
            url, code);
    curl_easy_cleanup(easy);
    return false;
}
return true;
  }
```

Main part of the code is above. I am using https://gist.github.com/bhardwaj75/7600b67726ae2cdbfcf8c9c74300ab69#file-libvev-curl-c code.

Answer (score 1):

The key is the [curl_multi_info_read()](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_info_read.html) function that returns info about completed transfers when the multi interface is used. Call that after `curl_multi_perform()` and timed out transfers will have that error code set.

See also the [Driving with the multi interface](https://ec.haxx.se/libcurl-drive-multi.html) chapter in the curl book, or a multi-interface using example such as [multi-app.c](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multi-app.html).